# Installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 dual boot Windows 10 Pro (1709) with Nvidia Quadro P2000

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 on a Lenovo ThinkStation (with Nvidia Quadro P2000) in dual boot with Windows 10 Pro 1709 already installed.

The first error I ran into was the following

```
BERT: Can't request iomem region
```

I got past this error by changing the **Secure Boot** option in the BIOS.

Now I am getting the following error

```
nouveau fifo sched_error 08
```

Initially it would not even load the Live Ubuntu.
I enabled the `nomodeset` option using the GUI (pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>) on the INSTALL UBUNTU screen, and then I was able to load the Live Ubuntu.

Now when I select the option to **Install Ubuntu** it does not detect the Windows installation (In the past I have installed multiple times and it always detected the current Windows installation and provided the option to install Ubuntu alongside) and wants to format the disk.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Please let me know if you need more specific information.

Comment: Have you turned off Windows fast start up? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions But if you are using f6, that is a BIOS boot, If Windows 10 pre-installed it is UEFI boot and you want Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. You have to then boot installer in UEFI mode and add nomodeset on Linux line. See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Boot Mode is set to AUTO.Boot priority at UEFI first. Now I am back at the "BERT: Cant request iomem region " error.

Comment: Ok. I was able to install Ubuntu after setting the nomodeset.I was still having problems booting so I again set the nomodeset on the startup screen and was able to boot.I then went to Software and driver update and selected the NVIDIA drivers (it was using the XORG nouveau drivers.The issue has been resolved.

Comment: @iamthecreator could you post the solution as answer to this post? Makes it easier for other readers to spot the proper solution to this issue. Even I overlooked the solution in the comments :P

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install Ubuntu after setting the `nomodeset` parameter. I was still having problems booting so I again set `nomodeset` on the startup screen and now I was able to boot.

I then went to *Software and driver update* and selected the NVIDIA drivers (it was using the XORG nouveau drivers).

The issue has been resolved.